# jquery behaves strangely in some sites when inserted via bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I'm putting together a bookmarklet that inserts jquery into pages it is invoked on. On many pages it works just fine, but on pages like http://www.cnn.com (which includes both prototype and scriptaculous) it behaves a bit strangely.

`$(blah..).appendTo("body")` does not work whereas `$(blah..).appendTo(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0])` works

`$("#id").hide()` , `.show()` and `.css()` don't work.

I've tried changing the variable from `$` to `jQuery` to `$k = jQuery.noConflict()` but the results are the same.

Note: On many web pages it works fine, only on cnn.com and a few others it does not.

Has anyone come across this, do you have any pointers??

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: Well, as I've noted I've tried using $k = jQuery.noConflict() to no avail. .hide(), .show(), .css() etc. still do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own q

The `Array.prototype.call()` in scriptaculous/effect causes this problem with jquery.

The solution is at http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/3248

Comment: molicule, that ticket does discuss this issue but it's not clear how you fixed the problem. i'm guessing you opted to refer to a more recent jQuery and this fixed it - is that the case?